# Parse JS SDK: How to set a default User ACL?

Tags: parse-platform

Conveniently this is blank in the [JS Docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#security-object-level-access-control)

Does an ACL have to be explicitly applied when each User is created?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. The following appears to work, applied right after new User is created (before calling the signUp method):

```
        var user = new Parse.User();
        user.set( userObj )

        var acl = new Parse.ACL();
        // apply desired ACL methods here..
        // by default, public read/write will be restricted
        user.setACL( acl );

        user.signUp( null, ... )
```

Initially, I tried passing `user` into `new Parse.ACL()` per Parse's docs, but that was not working.

(I'm now reading up on the Cloud Code because perhaps such security logic be better done there?)